# Why is onDestroy() method called?

Tags: android, timer, ondestroy

My app has 3 classes. First class is a splash screen, second class contains a list of playlists and third class that playlist's content. When a playlist is selected that third class get started to show the playlist content. On second class I have :

```
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        System.out.println("onStop Playlist!!!!");
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        System.out.println("onDestroy Playlist");
    }
```

and when third class is ready to start, I get on DDMS the messages :`"onStop Playlist!!!!"` and `"onDestroy Playlist"`. Why are this method called? Shouldn't be called only `onPause` method? The problem is that I want to stop some timer when app is finishing, but I don't know in this case where can I stop the timer. Any idea?

I call the third class like this :

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ViewPlaylist.class);
i.putExtra("id", idPlaylist[position]);
i.putExtra("timer", timerPlaylist[position]);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

The problem is that I call `finish()` ?

Comment: Its depends on How you called the Third class(start third activity). If you display some code then we can help you.

Answer (score 5):

If you read the docs for the [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) class(for the `onDestroy()` method) will see that :

> The final call you receive before your activity is destroyed. This can
>   happen either because the activity is finishing (someone called
>   finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this
>   instance of the activity to save space. You can distinguish between
>   these two scenarios with the isFinishing() method.

Answer (score 1):

Its because you are finishing the second activity with `finish()`. so instead of use `startActivityForResult()` and override `onActivityResult()` in second activity, So in this case your second activity's `onPause()` will be called, and when you `finish()` third activity you can back to your second activity's `onActivityResult()` method()

Try this code...

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ViewPlaylist.class);
i.putExtra("id", idPlaylist[position]);
i.putExtra("timer", timerPlaylist[position]);
startActivityForResult(i,RESULT_OK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you call `finish()`. This will finish, thus destroy that activity. Just remove the `finish()` call. It's only needed if you want to destroy a activity.

Comment: at another project, everytime  I started a new activity I called finish() I that solved the error OOM

Comment: I removed finish() but onStop is still called... why?

Comment: @Gabrielle `onStop()` is called because your activity is no longer visible to the user, the class with the playlist content covers it. This is a normal life cycle flow for and android app. In my answer i put a link where you can read more about how this life cycle methods are called and when they are called.